# create column names in a table with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA coding...my current question is how to create column names in a table using VBA...thanks to advice from stackoverflow guru's I have created to subs to do so...it works but it adds more columns than the listed array...not sure why this happens...any advice would be greatly appreciate...the code for the two subs is as follows...

```
Sub colNames()

 Dim lst As ListObject
 Dim currentSht As Worksheet
 Dim h As Long, hdrs As Variant

    hdrs = Array("Employee Name", "Hourly Rate", "Status", "Benefits?", "Street Number", "City", "Prov", "PC", "SIN #")
    Call CreateTable

    Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EmpTBL")

    Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    With lst 'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        For h = 0 To 8
            .ListColumns.Add
            .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = hdrs(h)
        Next h
    End With

End Sub

Sub CreateTable()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$D$16"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
        'No go in 2003
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
End Sub
```

these return a table but the first three columns beginning at B1 are column 1,2,3, then the array names?????

Comment: sub 2Sub CreateTable()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$D$16"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
        'No go in 2003
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
End Sub

Comment: You should learn how to debug a VBA routine - read this: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: good advice...thanks...will followup on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanations inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub colNames()

Dim lst As ListObject
Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim h As Long, hdrs As Variant

    hdrs = Array("Employee Name", "Hourly Rate", "Status", "Benefits?", "Street Number", "City", "Prov", "PC", "SIN #")

    ' first Set the worksheet object
    Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EmpTBL")

    ' now set the ListObject (table)
    Set lst = currentSht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, currentSht.Range("B1:B16"), , xlYes)
    With lst ' modify the Table object properties
        .Name = "Table1"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"

        ' replace the first column name with the first element in the array
        .ListColumns(1).Name = hdrs(0)

        ' loop throughout the other elements in the array (from 2nd)
        For h = 1 To UBound(hdrs)
           .ListColumns.Add
           .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = hdrs(h)
        Next h
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: how do I create a table without specifying a range?